# Why do I need to show uniqueness?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Question

Let $c$ be a cluster point of $A  \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose for every sequence $\{ x_n \}$ in $A$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$, the sequence  $\{ f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy. Prove that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists.

What I came up with for Proof:

Note that  $\{ f(x_n)\}$ being Cauchy implies that it is a convergent sequence. Let $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=L$

Then by Lemma 3.1.7: $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to c$

Lemma 3.1.7 is in our text book and states:

Let $S  \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $c$ be a cluster point of $S$. Let $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

Then $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to c$ if and only if for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ of number such that $x_n \in S  \setminus \{c\}$ for all $n$ and such that lim $x_n=c$, we have that the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $L$.

My professor mentioned that the first step should be to show the lim f($x_n$) exists.

Then the second step should be: If ($x_n$) is convergent to c then lim f($y_n$) exists.

Then he said that I need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n)$

I don't understand why I would have to do the second two steps

Comment: What is $(y_n)$?

Comment: $(y_n)$ is just another sequence he made up. I think it is arbitrary because in the problem it states for every sequence $(x_n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you need "uniqueness" is stated in your Lemma 3.1.7. (emphasis mine)

> Let $S  \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $c$ be a cluster point of $S$. Let $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
>
> Then $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to c$ if and only if for **every** sequence $\{x_n\}$ of number such that $x_n \in S  \setminus \{c\}$ for all $n$ and such that $\lim x_n=c$, we have that the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $L$.

It could happen that we have two different sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ that both converge to $c$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) \neq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(y_n)$.

Let me give an example. Consider $$f: [0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } x \leq 1, \\ 1, & \text{if } x > 1.\end{cases}$$
Now the sequence $\{1-\frac{1}{n}\}$ and the sequence $\{1+\frac{1}{n}\}$ both converge to $1$, but $$0=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(1-\frac{1}{n})\neq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(1+\frac{1}{n}) = 1.$$

Therefore you need to show that the limits for the different sequences coincide. And if they are not the same, then we can't give a meaningful value to $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x)$, because it depends on how you approach $c$. ($c = 1$ in my example)

Comment: doesn't  $x_n \ \in S$ \ {c} mean that you can't have a constant sequence $x_n=1=c$?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But instead we could consider the sequence $\{1-1/n\}$ and have the same problem. I'll fix my answer.