# Proving the limit exists when point tends to the cluster point of a set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let c be a cluster point of A $\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose that for every sequence in {$x_{n}$} in A, such that $\lim x_{n} = c$, the sequence $\{f(x_{n})\}_{0}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy. Prove that $\lim _{x\rightarrow c}f(x)$ exists.

I did not know how to approach this question, but I found a skeleton answer here:

[Why do I need to show uniqueness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203231/why-do-i-need-to-show-uniqueness)

I still don't understand how we show that the limit exists though.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb R$ is complete, so for each sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $A$ converging to $c$, the Cauchy sequence $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to some $\ell_\sigma\in\Bbb R$. Your first step should be to show that if $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two sequences in $A$ converging to $c$, then $\ell_\sigma=\ell_\tau$.

> HINT: If $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\tau=\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, consider the interlaced sequence $\langle x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots\rangle$.

Once you’ve done that, it’s straightforward to verify that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=\ell$, where $\ell$ is the common value of the limits $\ell_\sigma$.